# unable to create table Hibernate annotations

Tags: jar, command-prompt, hibernate-annotations, create-table

I am unable to create a table and insert the values into it using the Hibernate annotations. i am executing using command prompt. Following is my code.

**Contact.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class Contact {

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String email;
 private long id;

 @Column(name="Email")
 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

 @Column(name="First_Name")
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }

 @Column(name="Last_Name")  
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }

public void setEmail(String s) {
 email = s;
}

public void setFirstName(String s) {
 firstName = s;
}

public void setLastName(String s) {
 lastName = s;
}  

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
public long getId() {
 return id;
}

public void setId(long l) {
 id = l;
}
}
```

**FirstExample.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class FirstExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Session session = null;
  try{
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
   session =sessionFactory.openSession();
   System.out.println("Inserting Record");
   Contact contact = new Contact();
   contact.setId(3);
   contact.setFirstName("Tausif");
   contact.setLastName("rahmathullah");
   contact.setEmail("t.r@vl.net");
   session.save(contact);
   session.update(contact);
   System.out.println("updated");
   }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }finally{
   if(session!=null){

    session.flush();
    session.close();
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping resource="Contact"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**JarFiles**

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate3.3.1-slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.4.ga.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.0-bin.jar
slf4j-log4j-1.5.2.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
hibernate-annotation.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
```

**Log**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:87)
    at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:15)
```

I can compile without errors, but not able to run the app. I am guessing there's a problem with jar files. Please advise me on the above as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also am getting
resource : Contact not found.. please rectify this as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 <mapping resources> use <mapping class>
```

a silly mistake indeed. My app is now running perfectly!